# SELECT INTO in VBA results in no records selected or written

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

When I use this SQL in Access, it works fine.  In VBA, the result is to create a new table with no records.  It must be a dumb mistake on my part but can't find it.  Many thanks for any help or point in right direction.

Mike

```
strSQL = "SELECT tempconsoltb.[sub-accountNumber],tempconsoltb.[sub-accountDescription], tempconsoltb.sumOfCMBaseCurr INTO tblTempConsolTB FROM tempConsolTB;"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
qdf.Parameters(0) = Forms!frmMain.txtPM
qdf.Parameters(1) = Forms!frmMain.txtPY
qdf.Parameters(2) = Forms!frmMain.cboBaseFX
qdf.Parameters(3) = Forms!frmMain.cboConsolCo
qdf.Execute
```

Comment: you are selecting multiple fields in your query but you are capturing it in only one variable.Also i dont see any parameters in your query. Is there a where clause missing ?

Comment: Why are you adding parameters to the `QueryDef` when you have no parameters in your SQL statement?

Comment: If I don't add the parameter statements, I get an error that system was expecting 4 parameters.  These parameters exist on the main form and are referred to by other queries that are chained to this one.

Comment: you are selecting multiple fields in your query but you are capturing it in only one variable.Also i dont see any parameters in your query. Is there a where clause missing ?  I'm not sure what you mean by capturing multiple fields in one variable - which variable?

Comment: Is `tempConsolTB` the name of a saved query?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that the objects in your forms are named properly and are actually feeding the values into the query.   You can always use the Watch function in your compiler to see the values there or create a string variable that you initialize its value within the code to see what your actual query and put a watch on it when running the code.